# Are there any DLL files that an application written in Nemerle needs to include?

Tags: .net, deployment, nemerle

When I deploy an application written in Nemerle, is there any DLL file specific for Nemerle that needs to be installed? If there are such DLL files, which are they?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Optionally Nemerle.dll if you make use of things like "list". Also if you use Nemerle's linq provider then you would need Nemerle.Linq.

In more detail, Nemerle has 4 primary assemblies:

1. NCC.exe: A thin executable wrapper over Nemerle.Compiler.dll
2. Nemerle.Compiler.dll: The compiler itself.
3. Nemerle.dll: A library for things like list[T]
4. Nemerle.Macros.dll : Macros. Macros embeded in to your program when building so you generally don't need this dll to run your application
5. (Optional) Nemerle.Linq.dll: It has been considerd if linq macro should be part of Standart Library, but it relies on System.Core which is only for .NET 3.5+. So in order to support .net 2.0, this is an external macro.